# Why always have to force quit python launcher after running Tkinter on Mac?

Tags: python, macos

I'm using jupyter notebook on mac, recently I need to write interactive dialog box, so after google, I use Tkinter to make an interactive window.
But I was bothered by this problem couples day ,and still can't find a solution way.

Fisrt example:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename      
import sys
import os,time
def callback():
    name= askopenfilename() 
    print name

errmsg = 'Error!'
Button(text='File Open', command=callback).pack(fill=X)
mainloop()
```

Second example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys,os
class YourApp(Tk):
    def quit_and_close(self):
            app.quit()
            #os._exit(0)
            #sys.exit(1)
            #exit(0)
app = YourApp()
app.title('example')
app.geometry('400x300+200+200')
b = Button(app, text = "quit", command = app.quit_and_close)
b.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

And the third one:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
def ask_quit():
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "You want to quit now? *sniff*"):
        root.destroy()
root = tk.Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", ask_quit)
root.mainloop()
```

After running those above code, always need have to force quit python launcher.

[image]

It is very weird, and annoying because after forcing quit, I will got the error:

[image]

Is it necessary to use python launcher as default window? 
Is there possible to set another window to open ?
or is there proper way to close the launcher without causing programming crash?

p.s Even I try to use wxpython, it still open python launcher and got the same problem.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user (at least not for 20 years with a Macintosh) and not familiar with Python Launcher on a Mac, but can't you just start your python program from a shell and see if you have the same issue?

Do other python programs have this issue (I.e., not GUI ones)?

Comment: I  tried  imshow() through Atom editor before, as long as have to pop up another windows, it always shows up python launcher, and have the same problem: need to force quit .

Comment: Cmd+W works for me, closing the window, hitting the button in the window corner works, too. Both will call the quit callback defined in the WM_DELETE_WINDOW protocol.